# Authlogic :remember_me option don't work for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

Have such `user_session` model:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base

  logout_on_timeout true # default if false

  find_by_login_method :find_by_login_or_email
  remember_me_for 2.weeks
  logged_in_timeout = 16.minutes # default is 10.minutes
  #logged_in_timeout = 2.hours { :if self.record. }
  #remember_me true
  after_create :update_user_activity
```

When trying to create user session with `:remember_me=>true`

```
UserSession.create(:login => "login", :password => "my password", :remember_me => true)
```

usersession created, but user logged out after 16 minutes (no matter is  `:remember_me` set to `true` or `false` )

Also if `logout_on_timeout` set to `false`, when usersession don't end even after 16 minutes.

How is possible to make `:remember_me` option work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution at https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/pull/308 for this problem